# 5 How to set selected option in EntityType optionlist by given id

Tags: symfony

I'm new to Symfony and like to build a form for products with category as a dropdown preselected by the given category id from a get var like /new? category=1.
So far the categories are rendering correctly into a list by the EntityType how can I preselect the corespondig category? The user still has to be able to select another category so I don't like to just pass it to the product before saving.

Here is what I did so far:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)

        ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Category::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))

        ....

        ->getForm();
```

what I get in the view:

```
<select id="form_category" name="form[category]">
    <option value="1">Electronics</option>
    <option value="2">Clothes</option>
```

What I like to get

```
<select id="form_category" name="form[category]">
    <option value="1">Electronics</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Clothes</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form component is quite smart. It'll read from the provided object and write to it as well (which of course can be problematic at times).

To pre-set a field for the form, just set it on the object you give to the form builder:

```
$product = new Product();

if ($categoryId = $request->query->get('category', null)) {
    $category = $em->getRepository(Category::class)->findById($categoryId);
    $product->setCategory($category);
}
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)
// and adding fields, should remain the same
```

This should be enough to preselect the category.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! now it works. i tried a similar workaround before and now i found that the em passes an array and the setCategory has get an instanz of so i had to pass it as ->setCategory($category[0]) now it works